# Move constructor template elision

Tags: c++, c++11

For what reason move constructor call is not elided in following code?

```
struct Foo {
    Foo() = default;

    Foo(const Foo&) { cout << "Foo(const Foo&)" << endl; }
    template<class T> Foo(T&&) { cout << "Foo<T>(T&&)" << endl; }
};

auto f = Foo{};
```

Output: `Foo<T>(T&&)`

Checked on clang 3.3, g++ 4.9.

Adding defaulted or user-defined move constructor results in no output at all. Why the call to move constructor template is not elided by the compiler? And why the call to non-template one gets elided even if it's user-defined (i.e. how does the compiler know that it has no side-effects and can be safely elided)?

Comment: Have you tried different optimization levels?

Comment: Nope, I've used default flags, but it seems to be a matter of language standard, not optimization level (no optimization should change behavior of a well-formed program).

Answer (score 4):

To be a move constructor and thus candidate for elision, the constructor must not be a template instantiation (similarly, the fact that a template can generate a constructor with the same signature will not prevent the defaulted version to be generated).

In your example, the presence of the explicit copy constructor prevent the implicit generation  of a default move constructor, so the constructor template is instantiated (and is not a move constructor even if it share the signature).

If you add an explicit (default or not) move constructor, it will be used (and can -- but not must -- be elided).

Comment: So, you state that copy/move elision does not take place for constructor templates.
But why the addition of explicitly defaulted move constructor changes output?

Comment: Now I see the reason. User-defined copy constructor prevents compiler from generating move constructor.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to the standard for this claim re templates preventing elision?

Comment: @david.pfx, the places defining move/copy constructors (12.8/2) 12.8/3 in n3290 start with "A non template constructor for class X is a {copy,move} constructor if" and the place allowing elision (12.8/31) allows only elision of move and copy constructors.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because copy and move constructors are defined to be non-template (12.8/2, 12.8/3), copy/move elision rules do not apply for this constructor template (12.8/31).

The addition of defaulted or user defined move constructor (in this case) results in different output (and move elision) because user-defined copy constructor prevents compiler from implicitly generating a default one, thus the answer was wrong in first place:

> 12.8/7
>   If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, one is declared implicitly. If the class
>   definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy constructor is defined as deleted; otherwise, it is defined as defaulted (8.4).

Comment: Can provide a reference to the standard for this claim?

Comment: Not sure why this is not added in question itself.